# unity error CS0161 in my inventory system script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, game-engine

Hi im begginer of C# and unity and im making inventory, now im coding inventory system script and unity always giving me this error: **error CS0161: 'InventorySystem.AddToInventory(InventoryItemData, int)': not all code paths return a value**
i dont know what to do with it so there is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Linq;

[System.Serializable]
public class InventorySystem
{
    [SerializeField] private List<InventorySlot> inventorySlots;

    public List<InventorySlot> InventorySlots => inventorySlots;

    public int InventorySize => InventorySlots.Count;

    public UnityAction<InventorySlot> OnInventorySlotChanged;

    public InventorySystem(int size)
    {
        inventorySlots = new List<InventorySlot>(size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            inventorySlots.Add(new InventorySlot());
        }
    }

    public bool AddToInventory(InventoryItemData itemToAdd, int amountToAdd)
    {
        if (ContainsItem(itemToAdd, out InventorySlot invSlot)) // Check whether item 
        exists in inventory.
        {
            invSlot.AddToStack(amountToAdd);
            OnInventorySlotChanged?.Invoke(invSlot);
            return true;
        }
        else if (HasFreeSlot(out InventorySlot freeSlot)) // Gets the first available 
        slot
        {
            freeSlot = new InventorySlot(itemToAdd, amountToAdd);
            OnInventorySlotChanged?.Invoke(freeSlot);
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsItem(InventoryItemData itamToAdd, out InventorySlot invSlot)
    {
        invSlot = null;
        return false;
    }

    public bool HasFreeSlot(out InventorySlot freeSlot)
    {
        freeSlot = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: slot {.....} need to return either true or false

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a `bool` in your `AddToInventory` method as the exception message states. Currently, only your first if block within that method body returns a value. At a minimum you need to return true or false at the very end of your method outside of your conditionals (and you might want a different one in your else if block as well).

Example (keeping in mind this is a complete guess on what you plan to do with the return value):

```cs
    public bool AddToInventory(InventoryItemData itemToAdd, int amountToAdd)
    {
        // Check whether item exists in inventory.
        if (ContainsItem(itemToAdd, out InventorySlot invSlot))
        {
            invSlot.AddToStack(amountToAdd);
            OnInventorySlotChanged?.Invoke(invSlot);
            return true;
        }
        else if (HasFreeSlot(out InventorySlot freeSlot)) // Gets the first available slot
        {
            freeSlot = new InventorySlot(itemToAdd, amountToAdd);
            OnInventorySlotChanged?.Invoke(freeSlot);
            // should this return false? not enough information to know
        }

        return true;
    }
```

All this said, if you aren't ever returning anything but true, I would consider making this a void method and not return anything.